# Error in adding assertions in Soap UI

Tags: xpath, groovy, soapui, assertions

I am getting **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundSException** while trying to execute the below code in groovy script.
What could be the possible solution for it... Would be a great help if you guys can help me on it.

I have mentioned the code below:-

```
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project
    def testSuite = project.getTestSuiteAt(1)
    def testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseAt(0)

    wsdlTestSteps = testCase.getTestStepsOfType( com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep.class ) //test step

    def testStepCount = wsdlTestSteps.size()
    ( 0..< testStepCount).each
    {
            if (!(wsdlTestSteps[it].getAssertionByName("Not SOAP Fault")))
            { 
                wsdlTestSteps[it].addAssertion("Not SOAP Fault")
            }
            if (!(wsdlTestSteps[it].getAssertionByName("SOAP Response")))
            { 
                wsdlTestSteps[it].addAssertion("SOAP Response")
            }

     log.info("Assertion created into Teststep :: " + testCase.getTestStepByName(wsdlTestSteps[it].getName()).getName().toString())
    }
```

Also, is there any way that i can add schema compliance and xpath to the script?
Thanks,

Comment: to understand where exactly error occurred please provide full stacktrace

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
def testSuite = project.getTestSuiteAt(1)
```

This is the problem. You are trying to access a testSuite which does not exist. You have just one test suite

Make it (0)

```
 def testSuite = project.getTestSuiteAt(0)
```

It will work. Also whenever you get error see the line number it helps

[image]